# Aggregation over STRUCT in BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I ran the following query

```
WITH total_count AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    pid,
    click_ts,
    stacked ,
    SUM(stacked) OVER (PARTITION BY id, pid) AS total_count
  FROM limited_count),   
stacked AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM total_count
  WHERE stacked > 1
)

SELECT
  id,
  pid,
  total_count,
  SUM(stacked) AS stacked 
FROM stacked
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

I receive an error:

> No matching signature for aggregate function SUM for argument types: STRUCT. Supported signatures:
>   SUM(INT64); SUM(FLOAT64) at [21:47]

When I try to do SUM(stacked) on the following view:

```
WITH total_count AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    pid,
    click_ts,
    stacked ,
    SUM(stacked) OVER (PARTITION BY id, pid) AS total_count
  FROM limited_count), 

SELECT *
FROM total_count
WHERE stacked > 1
```

Everything works fine!
Any ideas how to make it in the same query?

Comment: Hi hamsy, please when making a question try to format your queries properly so it's easier to read. The easier it is to read your question the more likely you are to get an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH total_count AS (
  SELECT id, pid, click_ts, stacked ,
  SUM(stacked) OVER (PARTITION BY id, pid) AS total_count
  FROM limited_count), 
stacked AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM total_count
  WHERE stacked > 1 ) 
SELECT id, pid, total_count, SUM(stacked.stacked) AS stacked 
FROM stacked
GROUP BY 1,2, 3
```

Comment: It just gives me the amount of records, not the sum of values in the column though

Comment: Awesome! Worked! Thank you so much!